# High-Performance OpenGL 2D Shape Animation Library

Tags: opengl, animation, layout, vbo, graph-visualization

I'm looking for a high-performance library that can draw massive amounts (10's or even 100's of thousands) of relatively simply vector shapes (circles, arc or rounded rectangles) for visualization of 2D graph layouts.

I would like to be able to only transfer animation start and stop geometry and then "spawn" an interpolating animation on the GPU.

At each frame I want to minimize the amount of data from CPU to GPU by simply updating a global interpolation parameter typically from 0 to 1.

As I want to base this on OpenGL I believe Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) is what I should choose.

My language of choice is C++11 and my platform is Ubuntu 12.10.

Being able to layer high-quality text together with the shapes is a big plus.

What libraries/APIs should you recommend?

I believe oglplus is a good candidate, but I'm not sure if it's too low level for my task.

Answer (score 5):

If you're a beginner in OpenGL you'll hit a few bumps along the road. This is perfectly doable, but it requires some adcanced trickery. You need

- instancing
- curve interpolation in a vertex shader based on values you fetch from a "texture" holding animation control points, indexed by each instance's ID

  - and for curve interpolation to work for more complicated movements you must be able to split curves into segments (or patches) and index into those as well.

You should at least know how to draw simple shapes with OpenGL and how to write a vertex shader before you tackle instancing. It's not hard to do, but doing it the first time usually gives weird results, because you missed some index.

> What libraries/APIs should you recommend?

I recommend learning the required intellectual tools first, so that using such a library doesn't end in cargo cult programming.

You need

- linear algebra
- multivariate calculus
- nonlinear interpolation

  - polynom
  - Bezíer spline
- quaternions (for spherical linear interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what has been said here already ,if you target NVidia cards , you should take a look at [NVidia path extension](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/accelerated-path-rendering-opengl-nvidia-path-rendering-sdk).It basically allows you to load and render vector shapes on GPU directly with no need in triangulation etc.The downside here is that you should use fixed pipeline for this process(if using modern OpenGL set the profile to compatability).But the advantage is easiness of use and resolution independence.

Comment: Does fixed pipeline here mean that I can't transform (shift nor rotate) the object once it is on the GPU? If not, what does it mean?